# bootstrap 4 align text right cannot figure out

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

cannot get text to align right in bootstrap 4 looked at all docs and cant figure it out. I have tried several examples including these.

sample at http://exactcontents.com

text aligned right

text aligned right

does not align

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is aligned right correctly.

The problem is that  **The `<ul>` that contains those elementshas a width that not fills all the space available**. You can add a border to see that.

**Solution:**

1. Add `width: -webkit-fill-available;` to the `.navbar-nav` (this is the `<ul>`).
2. Delete one of the `<p>` repeated.
3. To the other `<p>` add the following styles:

```
width: -webkit-fill-available;
text-align: right;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just so i have this right your attempting to make your menu sit to the right side if so Edit your  to ml-auto not mr-auto

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

if its your 2

tags i would take them out of your ul parent and add them in a div which you can ml-auto